# How to use web worker on a npm module

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker, worker-loader

I'm writing a JavaScript library and I'm using a web worker. I'm using webpack (with worker-loader) to create my build.
Everything is working fine on the library.

webpack.config.js

```js
{
    test: /app.worker.ts$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
    ],
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            loader: 'worker-loader',
            options: {
                name: 'app.worker.js',
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

That generate :

```
/dist/app.bundle.js // my main library build
/dist/app.worker.js // my worker build
```

When I try to import my library on a react-application, my library try yo load the worker like this:
`http://localhost:3000/dist/app.worker.js`.
which obviously fail because it's located in `node_modules/.../dist/app.worker.js`.

I probably don't use worker-loader correctly.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I just found the problem.
I don't know why but the issue is related to yarn link. If I replace the `link:` with `file:` in my package.json, I don't have the problem anymore.

Another (non optimal) solution is to use inline:true.

Anyone know a solution or a workaround with yarn link ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit?  I'm having the same issue, but I'm using npm, and I don't have any `link` property in my package.son.  And when you say to use `inline: true`, do you mean in the options for `worker-loader`?